# I am getting the error "Incompatible types" but they shouldn't be incompatible (Java)

Tags: java, object, arraylist

In my main class I initialize some *Filters* and add them to the ArrayList *healthyFoodlist*. I then initialize the *healthyFood* Filter using this ArrayList.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main m = new Main();
    Filter veggieFilter = m.new SimpleFilter("vegetable");
    Filter fruitFilter = m.new SimpleFilter("fruit");
    Filter noPoison = m.new NotFilter("poison");

    ArrayList<Filter> healthyFoodlist = new ArrayList<>();
    healthyFoodlist.add(veggieFilter);
    healthyFoodlist.add(fruitFilter);
    healthyFoodlist.add(noPoison);
    Filter healthyFood = m.new OrFilter(healthyFoodlist);
}
```

Then in my *OrFilter* class I try to assign the first Filter in *healthyFoodlist* to a private Filter named *filter1*.

```
    class OrFilter implements Filter {
    private Filter filter1;
    private Filter filter2;
    private Filter filter3;
        OrFilter(ArrayList a) {
            filter1=a.get(0);
        }
    }
```

filter1=a.get(0); is where it says "Incompatible types, Required: Filter, Found: Object"

In the first block of code I am adding Filters to *healthyFoodlist*, not Objects, so why is this error occurring?

Comment: Shouldn't `OrFilter(ArrayList a) {` instead be `OrFilter(ArrayList<Filter> a) {`?

Comment: If you don't do this, Java sees `a` as a non-generic ArrayList, and Java only knows that these hold Object type, not Filter type.